# PHP display nested Object with array of other Object as 1 nested array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have big Object with protected properties and a property can be an array of other Objects. My goal is to print this entire Object as a single nested array. So I need to convert the object to an array.

I've tried doing:

`$result = (array) $object;`

But this converts only the highest lever object to an array and it messes up my protected properties names with weird question mark signs.

I've also tried something like this but this simply returns an empty array:

> $result= json_decode(json_encode($object), true);

Here is what my object looks like:

```
object(Handling\Model\SearchBooking\Booking)[133]
  protected 'jabooknr' => string '018024709' (length=9)
  protected 'jitsbooknr' => string '' (length=9)
  protected 'status' => string 'Y' (length=1)
  protected 'platform' => int 4
  protected 'agentid' => string '' (length=6)
  protected 'paymentInfo' => null
  protected 'transports' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(Handling\Model\SearchBooking\Transport)[145]
          protected 'depdate' => 
            object(DateTime)[146]
              public 'date' => string '2016-12-06 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
              public 'timezone_type' => int 3
              public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
          protected 'carriercode' => string 'TB' (length=2)
          protected 'carriernumber' => string '2067' (length=4)
          protected 'brochure' => string '' (length=6)
          protected 'pax' => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => 
                object(Handling\Model\SearchBooking\Pax)[147]
                  protected 'id' => int 1
                  protected 'title' => string 'MRS' (length=3)
                  protected 'firstname' => string 'MA' (length=7)
                  protected 'name' => string 'BEN' (length=5)
                  protected 'age' => int 58
                  protected 'luggage' => int 20
                  protected 'handLuggage' => null
              1 => 
                object(Handling\Model\SearchBooking\Pax)[148]
                  protected 'id' => int 2
                  protected 'title' => string 'MR' (length=2)
                  protected 'firstname' => string 'P' (length=6)
                  protected 'name' => string 'FT' (length=4)
                  protected 'age' => int 60
                  protected 'luggage' => int 20
                  protected 'handLuggage' => null
          protected 'departureAirport' => string 'BRU' (length=3)
          protected 'arrivalAirport' => string 'AGP' (length=3)
      1 => 
        object(Handling\Model\SearchBooking\Transport)[149]
          protected 'depdate' => 
            object(DateTime)[150]
              public 'date' => string '2016-12-13 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
              public 'timezone_type' => int 3
              public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
          protected 'carriercode' => string 'TB' (length=2)
          protected 'carriernumber' => string '2068' (length=4)
          protected 'brochure' => string '' (length=6)
          protected 'pax' => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => 
                object(Handling\Model\SearchBooking\Pax)[151]
                  protected 'id' => int 1
                  protected 'title' => string 'MRS' (length=3)
                  protected 'firstname' => string 'MANE' (length=7)
                  protected 'name' => string 'BN' (length=5)
                  protected 'age' => int 58
                  protected 'luggage' => int 20
                  protected 'handLuggage' => null
              1 => 
                object(Handling\Model\SearchBooking\Pax)[152]
                  protected 'id' => int 2
                  protected 'title' => string 'MR' (length=2)
                  protected 'firstname' => string 'PIRE' (length=6)
                  protected 'name' => string 'FYT' (length=4)
                  protected 'age' => int 60
                  protected 'luggage' => int 20
                  protected 'handLuggage' => null
          protected 'departureAirport' => string 'AGP' (length=3)
          protected 'arrivalAirport' => string 'BRU' (length=3)
  protected 'extraLuggage' => null
```

### EDIT

I have a method in my class where I "find" the result that looks like this:

```
public function findBooking()
{
    //here happens a bunch of logic to get the right result

    var_dump($object); exit; // this is the result that is show above        

    return $object;
}
```

Comment: Under normal use you cannot print protected stuff as it's not visible outside of the class.  You can do it with reflection, but it's not trivial, if you want to see an example you can look at my debug class here https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/blob/master/Evo/Debug.php although you will have to remove the environment check at the top for it to work (As I haven't separated this into it's own project yet)

Comment: Basically they are not in the visible scope from outside the class, if you where to change these to `public` to test it you would see that is the case.  This is sort of the point of protected...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I don't think that is an issue, I just need a way to convert my result to a single array to return it as JSON since it's actualy an API call response

Comment: No that is the case.  The only other way to do it is to write a function in the class called something like `toJson()`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes that is the goal but I don't know how to convert my nested Object to an array

Comment: If you want an object to be used with JSON, there is this neat PHP Interface called `JsonSerializable`, which will instruct the object to work with json_encode().

Comment: What is the end goal of this.  Do you want to create the json, and then use it to maintain the state of the class after reloading it from the json .. ?  If not you can do `var_export($obj, true)`  The second argument returns it instead of outputting it.  If you want to "reload" the class then you have to serialize/unserialize it.

Comment: As mentioned you could use `JsonSerializable` but you will have to do some additional work if you want to reload nested classes, as you have to structure it in a way that you can know what the class was an instance of, it's not enough to just serialize the data within the class.  PHP's native serialize will let you do this out of the box, but it looks like trash and is very hard to edit manually.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues, that make this difficult.

- Property visibility, (private, protected) can cause issues when trying to read them outside of the class, proper.  This is expected behavior as that's the point to not use public.
- Classes are different. They are well defined and we know them ahead of time, but they are too diverse to account of all property names, at least not with a lot of wasted effort.  Not to mention defining them "hard coding" would bite you later as it would make it difficult to maintain.  For example if one of the packages does an update and you have coded the property names in you may have issues if they change them.  On top of this given that these properties are not part of the classes Public "API" but instead part of the internals, it would not be unreasonable for them to change.
- Properties can contain a mix of data types, including other classes or objects.  This can make it challenging to handle.
- Classes are part of other packages/frameworks and editing them is not practical, this restricts us to working outside of these classes.

So given these difficulties I would recommend using reflection to access the protected properties.  Reflection allows you to inspect the definition of classes (and other stuff).

```
function jsonSerialize($obj){
    return json_encode(toArray($obj));
}

function toArray($obj){
    $R = new ReflectionObject($obj);
    $proerties = $R->getProperties();
    $data = [];

    foreach($proerties as $k => $v){
        $v->setAccessible(true);
        $property = $v->getName();
        $value = $v->getValue($obj);

        if(!is_object($value)){
            $data[$property] = $value;    
        }else if( is_a($obj,'\\DateTime')){
            //if its a descendant of Datetime, get a formatted date.
            // you can add other special case classes in this way
            $data[$property] = $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }else{
           $data[$property] = toArray($value); //call recursively
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

So assume we have these classes

```
class foo{
    private $bar; //private nested object

    public function __construct(){
        $this->bar = new bar();

    }

}

class bar{
    private $something = 'hello';
}

$obj = new foo;

echo jsonSerialize($obj);
```

See it in a sandbox [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/813b401fb2f8dcd7d0eb20044dd14acde85dcce6)

Outputs:

```
{"bar":{"something":"hello"}}
```

Also of note is we have a special consideration for the `DateTime` class.  Instead of getting all the properties of this we just want the date (probably) formatted in some standard way.  So by using [is_a()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) (I'm old school) we can tell if the Object `$value` has a given class as an ancestor of it.  Then we just do our formatting.

There are probably a few special cases like this, so I wanted to mention how to handle them.

Comment: Thank you for you very detailed response, but my goal is not to save or recreate the state of my objects. My goals is to simply convert my object to an array so that I can return it as json for example

Comment: Well as I said you cant do it from outside the class, as private and protected stuff is not visible.  It might show it if you do `(Array)` but it's gonna put some junk in the keys.  AS I said the best way is to write a function to return the json inside the class, you can use `JsonSerializable` interface    http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

Comment: But you still have to write the method that does it, which without seeing your class is a bit of a moot point.

Comment: I know I have to write the method but I don't know how to actually convert my object to json and I don't understand what the jsonserializable class does. I will try some stuff and I'll figure it out eventualy thanks anyways :)

Comment: Well you can just build an array `$data = ['foo' => $this->foo]` and then `return json_encode($data)`  Or you can use something like reflection get a list of the class properties and ltterate through them.  If it's a nested object give it the same method and then do `$data = ['obj' => $this->obj->jsonSerialize()]`

Comment: See without an intimate knowlage of your classes it's really hard to do it.

Comment: I am sorry but I honestly have no idea what you're talking about :p I can't imagine it's so hard to make an array from an object

Comment: I have edited my question so you know where the result that I've shown in my question comes from

Comment: @MikloV - there I updated it with some magic, because I'm cool like that.

Comment: I really appreciate what you're doing here but I don't think I can use it. Can you see my edited question? I added the code where and how I get my object result. I don't understand how I can use your trait and the other snippets.

Comment: if they are not your classes, you can simply extend them and then add the trait.  Say the built in one is `Booking` you make a class like this `class MyBooking extends Booking implements JsonSerializable{ use jsonSerialize; }` and it will inherent all of `Bookings` functionality.

Comment: So I only have to use the jsonSerialize in my Booking class? nothing else?

Comment: I get this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DateTime::jsonSerialize() in the trait

Comment: I have to go to bed, sorry.  No you either have to do it like `Update3` or you have to put it in all your classes.  you also have to poperly namespace the class names in `is_a` if your class is in a namespace you have to add  like `is_a($this,'\\DateTime')`

Comment: Like I said, i have to go to bed, sorry.

Comment: There just do it this way, it's probably the worse performance wise but, whatever I'm too tired.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is an old query, most answers are not easy to follow. So I tried to simplify the code for this specific question.

The cleaner way to get JSON objects is by implementing the JsonSerializable interface.

```
class Booking  implements JsonSerializable
{
protected $jabooknr;
protected $platform;
//Other attributes ....

//Array of tronsport
protected $transports;
protected $extraLuggage;

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'jabooknr'=> $this->jabooknr,
            'platform'=> $this->platform,

            'transports' => [json_encode($this->transports)
                ],

            '$extraLuggage' => $this->extraLuggage
        ];
    }
    public function __construct($jabooknr, $platform){
        $this->jabooknr = $jabooknr;
        $this->platform = $platform;
        $this->transports=[new Transport()];
    }
}
class Transport implements JsonSerializable{
    protected $carriercode;
    protected $carriernumber;
    //Array of Pax
    protected $pax ;
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'carriercode'=> $this->carriercode,
            'carriernumber'=> $this->carriernumber
        ];
    }
}
$booking = new Booking('018024709',25);
echo json_encode($booking);
```